Error: Cannot find module 'electron-squirrel-startup'
I'm trying to manage the setup events of my electron app made using squirrel. As suggested by the documentation, I'm trying to use squirrel startup on my main.js, but when I run the setup.exe i get this error "Error: Cannot find module 'electron-squirrel-startup'".
I've added the module as a dependency (not dev dependency) in my package.json.
Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?
I tried deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install again

Turns out I had node_modules included in packageConfig.ingore in my package.json and so the package couldn't be found. I think node_modules should actually be ignored, so I'm looking for a way to make it all work (not including node_modules during the electron-forge build, but ensuring electron-squirrel-startup is found on setup.exe execution)
